# WCF: How to Detect Disconnect and Get Original Context in WsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a `WsHttpBinding` request-reply service method that processes a transaction against a middle-tier service (which connects to the database) and returns a response message to the client with a transaction id.

I have a couple questions:

1. How can I detect when the client unexpected disconnects/faults before it receives the response?  I noticed the the channel_faulted event never fires for `WsHttpBinding`.
2. Assuming that #1 can be achieved, how can I get the original transaction id (that was in the outgoing response), in order to rollback/reverse that transaction that the client did not receive?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, in general, the service should have little to no knowledge ever of its clients.  The system should be designed in such a way that there's no tight coupling like this.

What this means for your scenario might be that you need to use Reliable messaging - something like `NetTCPBinding` or `WSHttpBinding`.  If messages aren't received by the client, your server will know.

I suggest you take a look at [chapter 7 in Juval Lowy's Programming WCF Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/). Chapter 7 is all about transactions in WCF.

Transaction support in WCF allows your clients to propagate their transaction to a WCF service.

If you're using WCF transactions and a call back to a client fails for whatever reason, the transaction will abort (answer to your second question).  In this way your service doesn't need to know anything about your client.  WCF takes care of it for you.

Lowy recommends a combination of reliable messaging and transactionFlow.  Something like:

```
<netTcpBinding>
  <binding name="TransactionalTCP" transactionFlow="true">
    <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
  </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm just not understanding something, but I'm not sure where the tight coupling is happening. Basically, I just want the service to detect when a client didn't receive a response, in order to revert any changes to the system. Unfortunately, the client will not able to enlist in any distributed transaction. The only thing we can do is keep our system in a consistent state, should a failure occur.

Comment: I've tried enabling Reliable Messaging, but through my own testing, the service still does not detect when the client has disconnected when sending back the response. Do you know through what mechanism the server can know when the client disconnects (e.g. an event)?

Comment: The tight coupling is that the service knows ANYTHING about the client.  It shouldn't know anything at all about the client - only the payload it receives from the client.